# Setting Applescript variable to list from text file

Tags: list, variables, random, applescript

I'm new to Applescript and the world of coding in general. I'm trying small scripts to get my feet wet and have some fun.

I want to make a random prompt generator. I know how to set the variable to a list but what I have in mind is much bigger than a few choices. I was wondering how to get the information from a text file. In said file I have over 200 prompts to choose from. I want to make a script that selects a random one from among these and displays them in a dialog box. I'm having trouble setting the initial variable to the contents of the file as a list. The follow up (random selection) I think I have a pretty good grasp on. I hope this is clear and thank you for looking.

Edit: 
Here's my code so far. I keep running into an error: "Can't make "/Users/Home/Desktop/text.rtf" into type file." Not sure what that means.

```
set draw_promptList to {}
set draw_prompt to read "/Users/Home/Desktop/text.rtf"
repeat with i from 1 to count of paragraphs in draw_prompt
set end of draw_prompt to paragraph i of draw_prompt
end repeat
set the list_count to the count of draw_prompt
set pick to random number from 1 to list_count
display dialog "Try drawing " & some item of draw_prompt & return
```

Edit 9/28:I fixed it per the revisions and it works. It does exactly what I wanted: selects a random word from among the long list of words in the text file.

```
set draw_promptList to {}
set draw_prompt to read "/Users/Home/Desktop/test.txt"
set the list_count to the count of paragraphs in draw_prompt
set pick to random number from 1 to list_count
repeat with i from 1 to count of paragraphs in draw_prompt
    set end of draw_promptList to paragraph i of draw_prompt
end repeat
display dialog "Try drawing " & some item of draw_promptList
```

Comment: If you're going to read a file to make a list out of it, then it should be a Plain Text file, not a Rich Text file. As to the error... "Can't make "/Users/Home/Desktop/text.rtf" into type file.", that means some part of the path filename is wrong.

Comment: BTW There are many other things wrong with your code besides the "Can't make "/Users/Home/Desktop/text.rtf" into type file." error, and you'll find that out after fixing that error.

Comment: Other issues: 1. `set end of draw_prompt to paragraph i of draw_prompt` should be `of draw_promptList`, you have the list name wrong. 2. `set the list_count to the count of draw_prompt` should be `to count of paragraphs in draw_prompt` 3. `set pick to random number from 1 to list_count`, you've set the _variable_ `pick` but do not use it elsewhere in the _code_ posted, so why is it even there?. 4 `display dialog "Try drawing " & some item of draw_prompt & return` should be `some item of draw_promptList`. You have the list name wrong and why append `return`, does it really need to be there?

Comment: I followed all these corrections and the code works! I've edited the question with your corrections. Also, I missed a line in my edit, apologies. To be 100% honest this code was Frankensteined. I cobbled it from other recommendations in other threads and boards because I had the darndest time finding information so I linked up ideas and experimented a lot. You've been a huge help. Thank you for your revision.

Comment: I appreciate the thanks, however the best way to express thanks in the SE Network is to mark the answer, that best answered your question, as accepted (click the check mark to the left of the answer) and or up vote them (click the up arrow to the left of the answer, if you have enough reputation) as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, *reading a file and turn each line of that file into an item in a list*, then here is one way it can be done.

```
set theFileOfPromptsList to {}
set theFileOfPrompts to read "/path/to/FileOfPrompts"

repeat with i from 1 to count of paragraphs in theFileOfPrompts
    set end of theFileOfPromptsList to paragraph i of theFileOfPrompts
end repeat
```

---

If you want to insure you don't add blank lines, *if there are any*, to the list, then use the following instead:

```
set theFileOfPromptsList to {}
set theFileOfPrompts to read "/path/to/FileOfPrompts"

repeat with i from 1 to count of paragraph in theFileOfPrompts
    if paragraph i of theFileOfPrompts is not "" then
        set end of theFileOfPromptsList to paragraph i of theFileOfPrompts
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: "reading a file and turn each line of that file into an item in a list"

Yes! That's exactly it. I have edited my question to include my code.